# How can I get the result of a command and its return code at the same time in a Bash script?

Tags: bash, bash-scripting

I am playing with Bash scripts. I'd like to assign the result of a command to a variable and its return code to another one.

Ex.:

```bsh
line_count=$(cat "$filename" | wc -l) #If the file does not exist, an error code is returned
cmd_return_code=$? #I want to assign the previous error code to a variable
```

I tried to use `$?` as shown above but it captures the return code of the previous assignment itself, which is 0.

How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: The commands you show set `cmd_return_code` to the exit status of the pipeline in the command substitution; i.e., the exit status of the last command in the pipeline (`wc -l`). If that’s what you want, what evidence do you have that it’s doing something different? If you want something different, what is it?  (P.S. Your command features a UUOC (useless of `cat`). `line_count=$(wc -l < "$filename")` would be more efficient, and might give you the results you want.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that in the pipeline `cat "$filename" | wc -l`, when the file doesn't exist `cat` will exit with an error, but `wc -l` will successfully count the 0 lines of text it receives from `cat`. The exit status of the last command in the pipeline is treated as the final status of the pipeline as a whole, so the whole pipeline is considered to succeed. Like this:

```
$ cat nosuchfile | wc -l
cat: nosuchfile: No such file or directory
       0
$ echo "$?"
0
```

Normally in bash, you can get the statuses of individual command in a pipeline with the `PIPESTATUS` array, like this:

```
$ cat nosuchfile | wc -l
cat: nosuchfile: No such file or directory
       0
$ echo "${PIPESTATUS[@]}"
1 0
```

...but that doesn't work with a pipeline in a command expansion like `$( )`, because that pipeline is going to execute in a subshell, and `PIPESTATUS` can't propagate from the subshell; only the final status gets passed back to the parent shell:

```
$ line_count=$(cat nosuchfile | wc -l)
cat: nosuchfile: No such file or directory
$ echo "${PIPESTATUS[@]}"
0
```

So, what can you do about this? Well, as l0b0 said, one possibility is to set the `pipefail` option. You don't have to do this for the entire script, you can set it just for that particular subshell by doing it within the command substitution:

```
$ line_count=$(set -o pipefail; cat nosuchfile | wc -l)
cat: nosuchfile: No such file or directory
$ echo "$?"
1
```

For this particular command, you can also eliminate the pipeline (it's what's called a [Useless Use of cat, or UUOC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#UUOC_(Useless_Use_Of_Cat))), and have `wc` read directly from the file, either by passing the filename as a parameter:

```
$ line_count=$(wc -l nosuchfile)
wc: nosuchfile: open: No such file or directory
$ echo $?
1
```

...or by using an input redirection:

```
$ line_count=$(wc -l <nosuchfile)
-bash: nosuchfile: No such file or directory
$ echo $?
1
```

There are a couple of differences between these two options: if you pass the filename to `wc` (and it exists), it'll output the filename as well as the number of lines:

```
$ line_count=$(wc -l realfile.txt)
$ echo "$line_count"
       6 realfile.txt
```

...while with the redirect option it won't. Also, with the second option the shell is responsible for opening the file (and handing the open file handle to the `wc` command), so if that fails it's the shell that gives an error (note that the error message comes from "-bash", not `wc`) and `wc` never gets run.

Answer (score 3):

**The [exit code](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/002) of an assignment of a [command substitution](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution) is the exit code of the command substitution.** See for example the exit code of `foo="$(false)"`.

To make the exit code of a pipeline the exit code of the the first failing command in the pipeline:

```
set -o pipefail
```